# iOS : How to avoid program quit during the 2nd call viewController?

Tags: model-view-controller, modalviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I've an iPad app that can call the 2nd viewController by pressing a next button. But when I press the next button, it is successfully called the 2nd viewController but when I press return the program quits (Program received signal). Anything wrong with my Xcode4 ?

```
.m mainController 

-(IBAction) next{

UIViewController * about = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"about" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:about animated:YES];

[about release];

}
```

.m 2nd viewController

```
   - (IBAction)btnReturn {

    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
- (void)dealloc
{
    [UIViewController release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two lines make no sense, you should remove them:

1. `[self.view removeFromSuperview];`
2. `[UIViewController release];`

Line 1: You don't have to remove your view from the superview. Dismissing the modal controller should be sufficient.

Line 2: If anything, you should release an object, not a class.